# Anime about mecha robots traveling into fairy tales

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've been trying to identify an anime from my childhood. Is a mix of sci-fi and fantasy. The plot was about some people that travel to fairy tales (or some world that resembles the ones in fairy tales) and fight people trying to change those stories (but I'm not be sure about this last part).

If recall correctly the good guys used mechas that looked like animals (panthers or wild boars) to travel into these fairy tale-like worlds. The anime aired on Cuban television in the '90s, so it is probably from the '70s-'80s or older. It was dubbed in Spanish.

The animation style resembles that of *[Ranking of Kings](https://myanimelist.net/anime/40834/Ousama_Ranking)*.

I'm inclined to believe it was a movie; if it is was a series I only saw one episode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anime I was looking for was [Time Bokan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Bokan). The real plot (from Wikipedia):

> Dr. Kieta, a somewhat wacky but intelligent scientist, has finally
> succeeded in inventing insect-shaped time machines called "Time
> Bokan". To prove its efficiency and safety, he decides to serve as the
> very first guinea pig for its maiden voyage. However, by the time his
> machine has returned, there's no trace of him inside. The only thing
> that it returns with is a talking parrot, along with a large gemstone
> called the Dynamond (ダイナモンド, Dainamondo), which is seemingly the most
> powerful and valuable jewel in the world.
>
> Now it's up to a search party, founded by Dr. Kieta's lab assistant
> Tanpei, to travel through time to find Dr. Kieta. However, it seems
> that someone power hungry is looking for the "Dynamond" as well.[1]
>
> The story starred two vividly opposing sides, the heroes, and the
> villains. Typical plots follow this format:
>
> The heroes travel to a particular era or space during their search for
> Dr. Kieta, and their hunt for the nature of the Dynamond, meeting the
> famous historical figures (and some times fictional characters) in the
> process. The heroes eventually encounter the villains. The two sides
> battle each other with their time machines. The villains always suffer
> a crushing defeat, either due to the smart foiling of their plans from
> the heroes, or due to the villains' own ineptitude.

In particular I was looking for a film called **Time Fighters in the Land of Fantasy**, that was made mostly of episodes themed around fairy tales.

Comment: It's great that you found it; could you add some details for future searchers?  Links can die, so having the information here is much better.

Comment: @DavidW Updated the answer! Let me know I there is anything to add

Comment: That's much better, thank you!